# Display `footnote`-template once at the end of each frame

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I'm working on `beamer` and setting up a custom `footnote`-template. In this template I invoke a macro which contains the footnotes.

The problem is, that `beamer` prints the contents of the `footnote`-template every time the `\footnote` macro was used. Because of that, if no `\footnote` was used the template isn't printed.

How is it possible to print the template once (and only once) at the *end* (so after any `\AddToFoot`) of each frame? A two run solution utilizing `footline` is not an option (well technically it is, but where's the fun in that).

An option which doesn't move any contents of the slide would be appreciated (so unlike my `\invisfootnote`).

Another template, which gets evaluated/used at the end of each frame would be fine, too, so it doesn't has to be `footnote`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \hfill\smash{\llap{\parbox[b]{5cm}{\footnotesize\myfootnotes}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\myfootnotes}{}
\newcommand*{\AddToFoot}[1]{\edef\myfootnotes{\myfootnotes#1\\}}
\newcommand*{\invisfootnote}{\smash{\llap{\phantom{\footnote{foo}}}}}% still takes up space
\let\footnoterule\relax

\makeatletter
%\def\@end@frame@hook{\invisfootnote}% doesn't work
%\edef\endframe{\noexpand\invisfootnote\unexpanded\expandafter{\endframe}}% doesn't work
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{with \texttt{\string\footnote}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
        \item Baz
    \end{itemize}
    \AddToFoot{foo}
    \AddToFoot{bar}
    \invisfootnote
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{without \texttt{\string\footnote}}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
        \item Baz
    \end{itemize}
    \AddToFoot{foo}
    \AddToFoot{bar}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Defining a new environment which calls the `frame` environment and something like `\invisfootnote` would work, but is definitely not the desired solution.

Edit2: What I'm actually trying to achieve is to rebuild the following template (the image is created using the code I already have with the two-pass solution to the footnote problem):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> based on clarification of the question in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39697331#39697331

The footnote mechanism works well, so I suggest to not touch it. Instead place the content of the footnote in a minipage with suitable alignment and the footnotes will be top aligned at a constant height.

(with some `xpatch` foo the code can probably simplified a lot...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak%
    % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
    \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
    \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
      \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
    \else%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
      \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
    \fi%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
      \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
        \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
        \else%
          \begingroup
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
            \begin{minipage}[b][0.5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}% 
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
                \insertshortauthor
                \insertshorttitle\newline
                \insertshortinstitute
            \end{minipage}% <----------------------
            \begin{minipage}[b][0.5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}% <----------------------
              \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
%              \footnoterule%
                            \usebeamerfont{footnote}
              \unvbox \beamer@footins%
              \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
            \end{minipage}% <----------------------

             \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}% 
                \centering \insertframenumber
            \end{minipage}
          \endgroup  
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode%
    }%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
      \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
      \else%
        \begingroup
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
            \begin{minipage}[b][0.5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}% 
                \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
                \insertshortauthor
                \insertshorttitle\newline
                \insertshortinstitute
            \end{minipage}% <----------------------
            \begin{minipage}[b][0.5cm][t]{.45\textwidth}% <----------------------
              \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
%              \footnoterule%
                            \usebeamerfont{footnote}
              \unvbox \beamer@footins%
              \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
            \end{minipage}% <----------------------

             \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}% 
                \centering \insertframenumber
            \end{minipage}
        \endgroup 
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode}%
    \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \fi%
  }
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{size=\tiny}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\institute{ins}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \footnote{Must not complain about beamer customisation}
    \footnote{Must not complain about too many duck images}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \footnote{Must try the new \texttt{tikzducks} package}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a (imho) small change to the layout, this is a hell of a lot of code and given the `beamer` documentation says something along the lines: "Use `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}`" this is overkill. I still think that applying small changes to the frame layout should be easier :)

Comment: @Skillmon I would not consider this a small change. It's like re-arranging the frame components to have the title on the bottom. Small changes (i.e. the alignment of the footnotenumbers) can be conveniently modified with `\setbeamertemplate`.

Comment: I was able to create my footnote layout based on your answer. Thank you very much!