# latex beamer footnote in footer

Tags: beamer, footer

I am working on a presentation. My presentation is made like this:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
colorlinks=true 
}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%installiert pgf, verbatim
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth*4/5]
\hspace{2em}
{\large\thesection.\thesubsection.~\insertsubsection}
\hspace{2em}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\begin{flushright}
\hfill\textcolor{red}{\rule{10cm}{.4pt}}\vspace{5pt}\\
\textcolor{gray}{{\tiny{~Name~\vline~\inserttitle~\vline~Folie~insertframenumber~\text{ }}}}
\end{flushright}
}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to put my footnotes in the footer. For Example: "My Car is red"^2. And in the footer on the left side I find: ^2 Book about cars, John et al., 2005. On the right  side the text defined in the preamble

Comment: have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388405/36296 helps

Comment: Maybe this one will help either https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290729/beamer-place-text-of-footnote-in-footline

Comment: The posts discuss the same problem but the recommended solutions do not work without a lot of source code. I am looking for a solution with \setbeamertemplate...

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{title}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
\parbox{10cm}{
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{10cm}{.4pt}}\newline
    \vskip1pt
    \textcolor{gray}{%
        \tiny
        \hfill Name~\vline~\inserttitle~\vline~Folie~insertframenumber\quad
    }
    \vskip3pt
}
}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
bla \footnote{Test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]